# Custom Widget is not visible in WIdget window

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I have created my own custom widget class, the code is below:

```
class myWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myWidget(QWidget*parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent){}
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event) override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event);
        qDebug()<<"Entered";
    }
};
```

In `widget.cpp` I have created it's instance, like below

```
myWidget *w;

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    w=new myWidget(this);
    w->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(138, 226, 52);");
    w->setGeometry(10,10,100,100);
    w->show();
}
```

As you can see my object is child of the `this` widget window but whenever I run the program it won't be visible to me in the window but when i go to top bottom i can see the console output of mine `Entered`, So it is present in my `Widget` window but I am not able to see it even I have set the background color as green, If I just use the `Qt` GUI to add one `Widget` into the form and set the background color and run the code then that `Widget` which I added from the GUI is visible but My `Widget` which i created by my own custom widget is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using `stylesheet` in the classes directly inherited from `QWidget` doesn't work. I override the `paintEvent` method of my program to get the desired output. Here it the `paintEvent` code, I added on my custom widget class,

```
 void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your class has to inherit from `QFrame` instead of `QWidget` in order to have the stylesheet working.